# Check VSA System - Acura TSX

Tags: acura, tsx, electronic-stability-control

Yesterday I started my car and had the Check VSA SYSTEM light on. I was not sure what it could be. After looking into some forums, I realized that it might have to do something with tire sizes (people using different tire size) - so I thought maybe I did not have enough air in my tires - anyway, i added some air, turned the car off/back on and the light disappeared.

This morning, I started the car and the check VSA system light came back on. So it defintely does not have to do with air. After driving for about 15-20 minutes, I pulled into gas station and turned car off/back on and the light is gone.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: what year is the car and have you had the codes read when the vsa light is on?

Comment: 2006 and no it just happened yeaterday. I should probably go to autozone or something @ben

Comment: autozone probably won't be able to read the codes. there may be a way to flash the codes. you're probably going to have to have a shop read the code.

Comment: @ben i read somewhere that it could also have to do with low break fluid. Have u heard anything like that?

Comment: maybe, i'd think the abs light would be on too though.

Comment: @ben light did not turn on yesterday afternoon or today

Answer (score 0):

VSA System light is the same as "Check ABS" or "Check Braking System."

Comment: Light did not turn on yeaterday afternoon or today